# What is std::contiguous_iterator useful for?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

For what purposes I can use it? 
Why is it better than random_access_iterator?
Is there some advantage if I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++17, there is no such thing as a `std::contiguous_iterator`. There is the [ContiguousIterator named requirement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator) however. This represents a random access iterator over a sequence of elements where each element is stored contiguously, in exactly the same way as an array. Which means that it is possible, given a pointer to an `value_type` from an iterator, to perform pointer arithmetic on that pointer, which shall work in exactly the same way as performing the same arithmetic on the corresponding iterators.

The purpose of this is to allow for more efficient implementations of algorithms on iterators that are contiguous. Or to forbid algorithms from being used on iterators that aren't contiguous. One example of where this matters is if you're trying to pass C++ iterators into a C interface which is based on pointers to arrays. You can wrap such interfaces behind generic algorithms, verifying the contiguity of the iterator in the template.

Or at least, you could in theory; in C++17, that wasn't really possible.. The reason being that there was not actually a way to test if an iterator was a ContiguousIterator. There's no way to ask a pointer if doing pointer arithmetic on a pointer to an element from the iterator is legal. And there was no `std::contiguous_iterator_category` one could use for such iterators (as this could cause compatibility problems). So you couldn't use SFINAE tools to verify that an iterator was contiguous.

C++20's [`std::contiguous_iterator` concept](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.concept.contiguous) resolves this problem. It also resolves the other problem with contiguous iterators. See, the above explanation for ContiguousIterator's behavior starts with us having a pointer to an element from the range. Well, how did you get that? The obvious method would be to do something like `std::addressof(*it)`, but what if `it` is the end iterator? The end iterator is not dereference-able, so you can't do that. Basically, even if you know that an iterator is contiguous, how do you go about converting it to the equivalent pointer?

The `std::contiguous_iterator` concept solves both of these problems. `std::to_address` is available, which will convert any contiguous iterator into its equivalent pointer value. And there is a traits tag that an iterator must provide to denote that it is in fact a contiguous iterator, just in case the default `to_address` implementation happens to be valid for a non-contiguous iterator.

Answer (score 8):

For a contiguous iterator you can get a pointer to the element the iterator is "pointing" to, and use it like a pointer to a contiguous array.

That can't be guaranteed with a random access iterator.

Remember that e.g. `std::deque` is a random-access container, but it's typically not a contiguous container (as opposed to `std::vector` which is both random access and contiguous).

Answer (score 4):

A random access iterator only requires a constant time `(iterator) + (offset)`, whereas contiguous iterators have the stronger guarantee that `std::addressof(*((iterator) + (offset))) == std::addressof(*(iterator)) + (offset)` (disregarding overloaded `operator&`s).

This basically means that the iterator is a pointer or a light wrapper around a pointer, so it is equivalent to a pointer to its elements, whereas a random access iterator can do more, at the cost of possibly being bulkier and being unable to turn it into a simple pointer.

Comment: Maybe &*((iterator) + (offset)) == &*(iterator) + &*(offset)?

Comment: @dasfex `offset` is a number

Answer (score 0):

As a C++20 Concept, I would expect you can use it to specify a different algorithm if the container is contiguous. Perhaps exploiting cache locality.